# Passing value to DB Helper

Tags: android, sqlite

I am passing the value to DB Helper to query, and I have 2 errors.

One in query

DB Helper:

```
public Cursor opis(final String sid){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    final String ID = sid;
    Cursor rezultat = db.rawQuery("Select opis from tablica where id = ? LIMIT 1" , new String[] {ID});
    return rezultat;
}
```

Error is on question mark:
[image]

Second error is in my MainActivity:

```
private void prikaz() {
    final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.idListView);
    ArrayList<String> theList = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor data = myDb.opis();
    if(data.getCount() == 0){
        Toast.makeText(this, "No data!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else
    {
        while(data.moveToNext()){
            String opis = data.getString(0);

        }

    }
}
```

Error:
[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

for the first error use

```
Cursor rezultat = db.rawQuery("Select opis from tablica where id = '"+yourvalue+"' LIMIT 1" , new String[] {ID});
```

for the secound you should pass String value to your method  `opis()`

Comment: Thanks first error fixed :)   myDb.opis(String.valueOf(sid)); this is passing ing in onCreate method.

Comment: @Zeljo  everthing is ok?

Comment: No see the post below

Comment: change this  `Cursor rezultat = db.rawQuery("Select opis from trupci_tablica where id = '"+ID+"'" , new String[] {ID});
` with this `Cursor rezultat = db.rawQuery("Select opis from trupci_tablica where id = '"+ID+"'" , null);
`
`

Comment: @Zeljo you are wellcome